# How can I access the stormpath user account's custom data via Aouth.io API?

Tags: android, ios, stormpath, oauth.io

I have integrated OAuth.io User Management with Stormpath. I need to access custom data of stormpath's user account using Aouth.io's Android and iOS APIs.

I am able to access user's firstname, lastname, email and id only but not custom data which I have entered through Stormpath's Editor in Accounts section.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OAuth.io provides a way for you to do that here: http://docs.oauth.io/#update-your-user-data

You can do something like:

```
user.data.firstname = 'Thomas';
user.data.someData = {
    a: 42,
    b: "some string"
}
user.save().done(function() {
    //todo when saved
}).fail(function(err) {
    //handle `err``
});
```

Comment: Thanks @rdegges. How can I get user data which is stored in stormpath?

Comment: When I use OAuthio's Android SDK and call OAuthJSONRequest().post from saveIdentitiy(), I get error message as "POST is not allowed".